# how to call this javascript function from inside another function?

Tags: javascript, html

```
pic_display+="<img src='"+pic_url+"' onClick='swapImage("+pic_url+");'>
```

I am adding an image to the innerHTML of a div with the code above.
I want to call the function `swapImage(pic_url)` whenever I click on the image.

I have still not figured out the syntaxes in javascript, always confuse them with php.

How should it be written ?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to wrap the function argument in quotes like you have with the src attribute. For example.

```
  pic_display+="<img src='"+pic_url+"' onClick='javascript:swapImage(\""+pic_url+"\");'>
```

Comment: There is no requirement to put javascript: in an onclick like that

Comment: The second suggestion is partly correct.  If pic_url can contain quotes, then you have a XSS vulnerability: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

If pic_url can contain ampersands, you might mangle the URL, e.g. pic_url = 'foo?a=b&lt=c&gt=d' should be converted to 'foo?a=b&amp;lt=c&amp;gt=d'.

Answer (score 1):

You could dump the quoting issue by using a variable instead of the string:

```
... onclick="swapImage(this.src)" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be like this `onClick='swapImage(\""+pic_url+"\");'`

Note you need to quote the pic URL when it is the argument since you are meaning to use a string and not a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
onClick='swapImage("+pic_url+");'>
```

try

```
onClick='swapImage(\""+pic_url+"\");'>
```